# How to get product name of Windows from Windows registry?

Tags: cmd

I need to get a value in a registry key with a Windows command.

For example:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName | findstr "REG_")
```

It outputs:

```
ProductName    REG_SZ    Windows 7 Home Premium
```

I need just the string `Windows 7 Home Premium`.

Comment: Maybe export it to a file? https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Command-line-options-for-Regeditexe

Comment: have you considered using a `FOR /F` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command **FOR** with option `/F` can be used to assign the output of a command or executable to an environment variable.

For usage in a batch file:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "ProductName" set "WindowsProduct=%%K"
```

For usage in a command prompt window:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName 2^>nul') do if /I "%I" == "ProductName" set "WindowsProduct=%K"
```

**FOR** starts one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line in the parentheses appended as additional arguments. So started is with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName 2>nul
```

The output of executable `reg.exe` is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after `reg.exe` terminated itself.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `reg` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output by `reg` on Windows Vista and later Windows versions is for example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
    ProductName    REG_SZ    Windows 7 Home Premium
```

So there is an empty line output first, next the line with the registry key, then the line with the value of interest with spaces around `ProductName`, `REG_SZ` and `Windows 7 Home Premium`, and last one more empty line.

But the output is different on Windows XP:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
    ProductName REG_SZ  Microsoft Windows XP
```

There is an additional header with two more lines output by `reg.exe` on Windows XP. There is a horizontal tab character between `ProductName` and `REG_SZ` and one more tab between `REG_SZ` and `Microsoft Windows XP` instead of spaces in comparison to output of `reg.exe` on Windows Vista and later Windows versions.

Those differences are taken into account on processing the captured output with **FOR**.

The first two lines are skipped because of using option `skip=2` which means on Windows Vista and later Windows version that the first line processed by **FOR** is already the line with the value of interest. But the first processed line on Windows XP is the third line which is an empty line. Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR**.

So the next line processed on Windows XP by **FOR** is the line with the registry key. It is split up into substrings using the default delimiters normal space and horizontal tab which means here that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows` is assigned to the specified loop variable `I` and `NT\CurrentVersion` to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) because of option `tokens=1,2*`.

Therefore on Windows XP the **IF** condition is executed to case-insensitive compare the string assigned to loop variable `I` with `ProductName` which evaluates to false in this case.

Then the fifth line of `reg` output on Windows XP is processed like the third line of `reg` output on Windows Vista and later Windows versions.

The line with the value of interest is split up into three substrings. The first space/tab delimited string `ProductName` is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. The second space/tab delimited string `REG_SZ` is assigned to loop variable `J`. The rest of the line after the spaces/tabs after `REG_SZ` is assigned completely with the spaces to next but one loop variable `K` because of `*` at end of option string `tokens=1,2*` after `2`.

The **IF** condition is true for that line and so the string value of interest is assigned to the environment variable `WindowsProduct`.

The last empty line is again ignored by **FOR**.

So finally the environment variable `WindowsProduct` is defined with the string value of interest if found at all in Windows registry.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`